# Find the first tuple in anything that is or might contain a tuple?

Tags: python, list, parsing, tuples

In Python, what is a simple way to always return a tuple whether the variable in question holds a tuple or a list containing at least one tuple?

```
# (3, 5) would return (3, 5)
#
# [(3, 5), [200, 100, 100]] would return (3, 5)
#
# [[100, 100, 100], (3, 5)] would return (3, 5)
#
# [(3, 5), (4, 7)] would return (3, 5)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I actually *needed* something like this, I would do something like:

```
def first_tuple(t):
    return t if isinstance(t,tuple) else next(x for x in t if isinstance(x,tuple))
```

demo:

```
>>> first_tuple((3,5))
(3, 5)
>>> first_tuple([(3, 5), [200, 100, 100]])
(3, 5)
>>> first_tuple([[100, 100, 100], (3, 5)])
(3, 5)
>>> first_tuple([(3, 5), (4, 7)])
(3, 5)
>>> first_tuple([[],[]])
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<stdin>", line 2, in first_tuple
StopIteration
```

Generally speaking, you *shouldn't need* something like this.  IMHO, this seems like it is probably a poor design and the data-structure here should be reconsidered.

Comment: Possible a poor design- but I'm having to write a really general search algorithm that handles state-spaces in a lot of different formats. This is a huge help, also in learning python, thank you

Comment: @rob-gordon -- No problem.  I'm happy to help :).  This answer combines a python conditional expression with a generator expression (which is similar to a list comprehension).  (I'm mainly writing out the names of these things so you can google them if you have questions).

Comment: You are looking for [this](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/175655/python-forgiveness-vs-permission-and-duck-typing/175663#175663). About should you check your own code for validity or not...